# dtplyr cannot be used with illegal name

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, dtplyr

I'm working with the following sample data:

```r
library(data.table)
library(dtplyr)
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(a = c(1,1,3), b = c(4:6))

names(df) = c('aa aa', 'bb bb')

df_dt = lazy_dt(df)

df_dt %>% group_by(`aa aa`) %>% slice(n())
```

However, I encountered this error:

```
Error in .checkTypos(e, names_x) : 
  Object '`aa aa`' not found amongst aa aa, bb bb
```

Could you help me understand if I've overlooked something or made an error? Thank you.

Comment: This is a bug which was already reported on [GH](https://github.com/tidyverse/dtplyr/issues/451) and which is fixed in the devel version, i.e. after running `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dtplyr")` your code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `df_dt` is not a `data.frame`. The functions `group_by` and `slice` work on data.frame. But `df_dt` is not a `data.frame`. You can check it using `class(df_dt)`.

If it is a `data.frame` or `tibble`, then only the code will work. But `df_dt$parent` is a `data.frame`.

Try to modify the code

```
df_dt$parent |> group_by(`aa aa`) %>% slice(n())
```

This will give you desired result.

Edit: After the follow-up question about using `dplyr::slice` without subsetting, I want to clarify further.

The `dplyr::clarify` expects the input to be a `data.frame`. If you run `class(df_dt)`, the output is

```
class(df_dt)
[1] "dtplyr_step_first"
[2] "dtplyr_step"
```

This means `dplyr::slice` will not work on `df_dt` object.
But if you run `class(df_dt$parent), the output is

```
class(df_dt$parent)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

That means, you can run `dplyr::slice` on this object. When I attempted it, the output is

```
df_dt$parent |> group_by(`aa aa`) %>% slice(n())
# A tibble: 2 × 2
# Groups:   aa aa [2]
  `aa aa` `bb bb`
    <dbl>   <int>
1       1       5
2       3       6
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Is it possible to use dtplyr::slice directly without subset the `parent` element inside `df_dt`?

Comment: The use of `$parent` defeats the purpose of using `lazy_dt(.)`, you might as well do `as.data.table(df) %>% group_by(....)` or `tibble(df) %>% group_by(...)`. That is, if the intent is to lazily accumulate/translate the operations (a tenet of `dtplyr`'s purpose) and then execute in `data.table`-canonical (referential, when able) mechanics. By using `$parent`, you are bypassing `dtplyr` and only using `dplyr`.